# S3Transfer download_file errors out, but client.download_file works fine

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm using Boto in Python to download a file from my S3 bucket.

This works fine:

```
import boto3
s3_client = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_client.meta.client.download_file('mybucket', 'db/file.00.txt', '/work/testing/file.00.txt')
```

I would like to use S3Transfer to automatically use multipart, as I will be working with some pretty massive files (900 MB+).

However, when I try the following, it fails:

```
import boto3
from boto3.s3.transfer import S3Transfer
s3_client = boto3.resource('s3')
transfer = S3Transfer(s3_client)
transfer.download_file('mybucket', 'db/file.00.txt', '/work/testing/file.00.txt')
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/work/sparkrun/CommonBlast.py", line 126, in <module>
    transfer.download_file('mybucket', 'db/file.00.txt', '/work/testing/file.00.txt')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 658, in download_file
    object_size = self._object_size(bucket, key, extra_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 723, in _object_size
    return self._client.head_object(
AttributeError: 's3.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'head_object'
```

The parameters to the download_file method are identical. I'm using the latest version of boto (1.2.3). What is going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're passing in a resource when `S3Transfer` expects a client.

You'll also never need to create your own `S3Transfer` object anyway because its methods are added to both the client and the resource already.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3')
client.download_file('bucket', 'key', 'filename.txt')

resource = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = resource.Bucket('bucket')
bucket.download_file('key', 'filename.txt')

obj = bucket.Object('key')
obj.download_file('filename.txt')
```

[docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/s3.html#using-the-transfer-manager)

Comment: Ah, that would be why. Works great now, thanks. I guess that will teach me to pay closer attention.